# How to add NULL to a union of multiple tables that don't have the same number of columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, union-all

I am trying to do a union of ten tables, all of which I want in a single flat file for data visualization. They share a lot of columns in common, but there is a decent amount of columns unique to each table that won't exist in others.

If it were only a few columns, I would do the following (see below) but this would take way too long for all of the columns and tables I am working with. Is there a way to do this without going through each column individually with `NULL AS 'missingColumn'`

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1, COL2, NULL AS COL3 FROM TABLE 2
```

I am using SQL Server

Thank you!

Comment: I am using SQL Server v 18.5

Comment: you wil need a huge script to map all the tables and column that are missing and needed to be replaced. I would misstrust a design that has to many columns and when you can union them there could be a lot of redundancy. So check first if you are normalized and then write a clear query will all the NULL added manually, to fish for errors in a big script is timeconsuming

Comment: The names and data types for columns are taken from the first part of a union, you don't need to specify any aliases in the second and subsequent parts of unions. i.e.: just use `null` as opposed to `null as col3`.